# Unable to configure JNDI Read & Connect Timeout properties through Java VM options

Tags: java, jndi

I have configured JNDI read & connect timeout properties through VM options as shown below:

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=5000
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout=5000
```

But it is not working. JNDI read time out fails with below exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:-1ms.
```

But if I configured these properties in JNDI environment properties as shown below:

```
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "5000");
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "5000");
```

Then it works correctly I get the proper error message for the read time out as shown below:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:5000ms.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that JNDI properties are not system properties, so setting them as system properties has no effect. You can provide them either in the environment of a `Context` or else via a `/jndi.properties` file in the root directory of your JAR file.